# The resource exceeds the maximum size on iOS 13

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, rx-swift

With my app, when I launch to iOS 11 (iPhone 6) all is OK.

But on iOS 13 (iPhone SE) I get this error message:

[image: Capture on iOS 13]

In English:

> The resource exceeds the maximum size

Here the content of my Podfile

```
pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
pod 'Stripe'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'
pod 'AWSS3'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'MQTTClient'
pod 'GooglePlaces', '= 3.0.3'
pod 'GoogleMaps', '= 3.0.3'
pod 'libPhoneNumber-iOS'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack/Swift'
pod 'RxAlamofire/RxCocoa'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'FBSDKPlacesKit'
pod 'OneSkyOTAPlugin'
```

Comment: Do you download something at launch? How many memory space do you on your iPhone?

Comment: 116 gb it's new phone , and it's with TestFlight i test my app , on Iphone 6 (IOS 11) all is ok

Answer (score 5):

If this error occurs after network request, that means you use `GET` method instead of `POST`

Comment: Yes good info but why it's good on ios 11 with iphone 6 and not with IOS 13.5 (Iphone SE)

Comment: Now i changed JSONEncoding.default to URLEncoding.default and it's worked , but i don't know why ?